# Flutter IOS - Archiving IOS package on Github Actions

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying export an IOS archive of flutter app on Github action. So I made a workflow that looks like:

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploying to Testflight
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Fetch flutter dependencies
        run: flutter pub get
      - name: Force Xcode 11
        run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.4.app
      - name: installing pods
        run: (cd ios && pod install)
      - name: Archiving project
        env:
          PR_NUMBER: $(jq --raw-output .pull_request.number "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH")
        run: ./.github/scripts/archive_app.sh
      - name: Exporting .ipa
        run: ./.github/scripts/export_ipa.sh
```

the content of `archive_app.sh` is:

```
set -eo pipefail


xcodebuild -workspace $PWD/ios/Runner.xcworkspace \
-scheme productionMyApp \
-archivePath $PWD/build/Runner.xcarchive \
-configuration Release-productionMyApp \
archive | xcpretty
```

if I run this script locally, the command runs to completion without any issue. If I run it on Github Actions, I get an error in the mid of compiling and building the dependencies:

```
....
▸ Compiling Pods-Runner-dummy.m
▸ Compiling Pods_Runner_vers.c
▸ Compiling Pods-Runner-dummy.m
▸ Compiling Pods_Runner_vers.c
▸ Touching Pods_Runner.framework
▸ Building Runner/Runner [Release-productionMyApp]
▸ Check Dependencies
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
##[error]Process completed with exit code 65.
```

The xcode compatibility of my project is 11.4.

Comment: Can you provide more log messages, there should be one or more errors that should give you more information about why it failed.